# Getting Download Link of Last Downloaded File - Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to get link of Last Downloaded file in Selenium Python. The following is the download Button for downloading. It doesn't show any link.

```html
<button id="download_mi_button" class="btn btn-success btn-pill btn-lg w-50"> Download File</button>
```

So I thought to download the file and then get the link of the last downloaded file and possibly cancel the downloading too as I just need the link.

Page URL : https://mifirm.net/download/5612

Download Button Text : Download Server Xiaomi

Comment: The actual link can be contained in some other element or dynamically created by JavaScript. Please share a link to the page you are working with if you want us to help you with this.

Comment: Updated the Question with the page url.

Comment: I couldn't find the downloading file link inside elements there, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things to be noted down.

1. You'd have to `scroll down till the web element` is in Selenium view port.
2. Launch `browser` in full screen mode.
3. Use `explicit waits.`
4. There's `no link in HTML body`, but download is appearing in `chrome://downloads`, so we can navigate to `downloads` section and then the can a grab a link, (Please see below)
5. Also, the desired link is in shadow-root element which has to handle via JS call.

**Code :**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
#driver.implicitly_wait(50)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.get("https://mifirm.net/download/5612")
ele = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[id='download_mi_button']")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", ele)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", ele)
time.sleep(3)
driver.get("chrome://downloads/")
time.sleep(3)

download_link = driver.execute_script('return document.querySelector("body > downloads-manager").shadowRoot.querySelector("#frb0").shadowRoot.querySelector("#url")')
print(download_link.get_attribute('href'))

Cancel_Button = driver.execute_script('return document.querySelector("body > downloads-manager").shadowRoot.querySelector("#frb0").shadowRoot.querySelector("#safe > div:nth-child(6) > cr-button")') 
Cancel_Button.click()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```